# Power Query: How to insert a Column using the Left(Right Function based on A4

Tags: powerquery, m

Is there a way to Add a column, in Power Query, by referencing data in a specific cell?

I want to take the text from `"A4"`, use a `Left(Right function`, and add that to a new column.

My VBA macro is:
"Latest 4 Wks - Ending " & Left(Right(.Range("A4"), 24), 23)

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through further research, I found that by adding a Blank Query, I was able to add a column, in Power Query, by referencing data in a specific cell?

Insert BlankQuery
Advance Editor

```
(YourWorkSheet as table ) as text=>
let

    SheetCellA4 =YourWorkSheet[Column1]{3},
    SplitByFrom = Text.Split(SheetCellA4, "to "){1},
    SplitByTime = Text.Split(SplitByFrom, "`"){0} 
in SplitByTime
```

The bring in the worksheet data
After the `Source` line

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Query1(Source))
In
#"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to do something like that. In a first step you define a named range for A4 which I named *cellA4*. I then did a load into Powerquery, added an extra column with the part of the text (I used [Text.Middle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-middle) other text function are possible, of course) from the cell and drilled down to the content of the cell. The M-code for that is

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="cellA4"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Middle([Column1],23)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1"}),
    Custom = #"Removed Columns"{0}[Custom]
in
    Custom
```

Result looks like

[image]

Them I just made a table with one column and imported that into Powerquery and added an extra column which just contains the text from cell A4. M-Code is

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each cellA4)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  However, I'm lost starting at: "Result Looks Like:"  The M-code is being placed in the `Add Custom Column` field, right? Once I click ok, the Column shows: "From: 2020  PD 09  WK 1  (33) to 2020  PD 09  WK 4  (36)`"

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean that you made a table with one column and imported that into Powerquery and added an extra column which just contains the text from cell A4... Why would I need to do this?

Comment: Before I try to explain anything to you is the result at the end of my answer what you want after all?

Comment: Sorry, no:  it's giving me: From: 2020 PD 09 WK 1 (33) to 2020 PD 09 WK 4 (36)`   All I need is: 2020 PD 09 WK 1 (33) to 2020 PD 09 WK 4 (36)

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand but _2020 PD 09 WK 1 (33) to 2020 PD 09 WK 4 (36)_ is the result in my example. So, if that's what you want then you can use the solution I proposed. You might possibly need, of course, to adjust, the text function I used.

Comment: The From is still populating, but yes I changed the text function from 23 to 29 characters, and it worked, except I need to take off the apostrophe at the end - after (36).  What would be the function for that if I kept the `text.middle` pelase?

Comment: And then my next question would be, is there a way to keep the named region, after I update and save over the workbook.  I want to keep refreshing the data every month.

Comment: `Text.Middle` has an optional parameter, so you could try `Text.Middle([Column1],23,41)`. Or you use other functions, look https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/08/20/5-very-useful-text-formulas-power-query-edition/. The answer to your second question is AFAIK no but on the other hand if you get new data every month you should import this new  data into  Powerquery and do the stuff you need to do.